# What possible values of $a$ lead to the inequality $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \gt |g(x_1) - g(x_2)|$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and define
$$f(x) = e^x, \quad g(x) = x^2 + ax + 1.$$
Find the possible values of $a$ such that for all $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 2], x_1 \not = x_2$, $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \gt |g(x_1) - g(x_2)|.$$

---

By factorizing we have $$|e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}| \gt |(x_1 - x_2)(x_1 + x_2 + a)|.$$ But I am not sure how to proceed. In particular, I don't know how to deal with the absolute values and the two variables. Assume that $x_1 \gt x_2$ (without loss of generality) and we have $$\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2} \gt |x_1 + x_2 + a|,$$ but that doesn't seem to yield any solution.

This question is about derivatives, if that helps.

Comment: For those who downvoted and voted to close this question, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x \in [0, 2]$, under the given condition, it follows that for $t > x$, 
$$\left|\frac{e^t - e^x}{t - x}\right| > \left|\frac{g(t) - g(x)}{t - x}\right|. \tag{1}$$
Let $t \downarrow x$, we then have (treat boundary points similarly)
$$e^x \geq \left|g'(x)\right| = \left|2x + a\right| \quad \text{ for all } x \in [0, 2] \tag{2}$$
Geometrically, $(2)$ implies that the graph of $y = e^x$ always sits at the top of the graph of $y = |2x + a|$.

If $a \geq 0$, since $x = \log 2 \in [0, 2]$ and $e^{\log 2} = 2$, the intercept of the line $y - 2 = 2(x - \log 2)$ is $2 - 2\log 2 > 0$, thus $a \in [0, 2 - 2\log 2]$.

If $a < 0$, on $(0, +\infty)$, $y = |2x + a|$ has a ''V'' shape, with the intersection with the $x$-axis at $-a/2$, and the intersection with $y$-axis at $-a$. If $-a/2 \geq 2$, then $-a \leq 1$ guarantees $(2)$, but these two conditions are inconsistent. Thus we consider the case $-a/2 < 2$, for which case $-a \leq 1$ and $4 + a \leq e^2$ ensure $(2)$. Solve these inequalities gives $a \geq -1$.

In summary, we conclude that if $a \in [-1, 2 - 2\log 2]$ then we can guarantee $(2)$. We need also to check for $a \in [-1, 2 - 2\log 2]$, we indeed have $|g(x_2) - g(x_1)| < |f(x_2) - f(x_1)|$. In fact, in view of $(2)$, for $x_2 > x_1$, if $a \in [0, 2 - 2\log 2]$, then
\begin{align}
& |f(x_2) - f(x_1)| = e^{x_2} - e^{x_1} \\
= & \int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^t dt \\
\geq & \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |2t + a| dt \quad \text{because $(2)$ holds, given $a \in [0, 2 - 2\log 2]$}\\
= & \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (2t + a) dt \\
= & x_2^2 - x_1^2 + a(x_2 - x_1) = |g(x_2) - g(x_1)|.
\end{align}
If $a \in [-1, 0)$, for which case we should discuss where $x_1$ and $x_2$ located, if $\max\{x_1, x_2\} < -a/2$, then
\begin{align}
& \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |2t + a| dt \\
= & -\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (a + 2t) dt \\
= & -a(x_2 - x_1) - (x_2^2 - x_1^2).
\end{align}
Note that since $x_1 + x_2 < -a$, the last expression is positive and equals to $|g(x_2) - g(x_1)|$. The case of $\min\{x_1, x_2\} \geq -a/2$ can be treated in a similar manner. For the case $x_1 < -a/2 < x_2$:
\begin{align}
& \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |2t + a| dt \\
= & \int_{x_1}^{-a/2} |2t + a| dt + \int_{-a/2}^{x_2}|2t + a| dt \\
= & -\int_{x_1}^{-a/2} (a + 2t) dt + \int_{-a/2}^{x_2}(2t + a) dt \\
= & x_1^2 + x_2^2 + a(x_2 + x_1) + a^2/2
\end{align}
Careful calculation shows that 
\begin{align}
& x_1^2 + x_2^2 + a(x_2 + x_1) + a^2/2 - |g(x_2) - g(x_1)| \\
= & \frac{1}{2}(2x_1 + a)^2I(x_1 + x_2 > -a) + \frac{1}{2}(2x_2 + a)^2I(x_1 + x_2 \leq -a) \geq 0.
\end{align}

We therefore showed that if $a \in [-1, 2 - 2\log 2]$, then $|f(x_2) - f(x_1)| > |g(x_2) - g(x_1)|$. If you need strict inequality, we can set $a \in (-1, 2 - 2\log 2)$, for safety.

Comment: I understand you, but does $(2)$ imply $(1)$?

Comment: I added more details. Please check.

Comment: Why $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} |2t + a| dt = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (2t + a) dt$?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie Because $a \geq 0$, $x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0$, we can remove the $||$.

Comment: I see. But this seems to be quite complicated. And seriously, we haven't learned integrals yet. Can you think up another method?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You have almost reached your solution.

$$\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2} \gt |x_1 + x_2 + a|$$
$$\Rightarrow  |x_1 + x_2 + a| \lt \frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}$$
$$\Rightarrow  -\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2} \lt x_1 + x_2 + a \lt \frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}$$
$$\Rightarrow  -\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}-(x_1 + x_2)  \lt a \lt \frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}-(x_1 + x_2)$$

So $a$ lies in the interval $\{-\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}-(x_1 + x_2),\frac {e^{x_1} - e^{x_2}}{x_1 - x_2}-(x_1 + x_2)\}$

Now you just need to apply one more condition to this solution to get the correct answer: $$x_1,x_2 \in [0,2]$$
And this *can be done* without derivatives.

Can you complete the answer now?

**P.S.** However if you seek to do it the *derivatives* way, try to use [Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Lagrange%27s_Mean_Value_Theorem). Then we will get the same solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to proceed? Can you elaborate on that? Also, I know Lagrange's Mean Value theorem but I still don't know how to use it.

Comment: 1. Try to maximise the length of the interval by choosing appropriate $x_1,x_2$ from the domain by any method you like. 2. Using LMVT, for a certain $x$, by dividing both sides of the inequality by a positive $|x_1-x_2|$, you get $|f'|>|g'|$ and then you get the answer.  Observe that the conditions for LMVT are satisfied by the functions.

Comment: Sorry, this might seem stupid (in view of all the down votes), but I really don't understand. 1. How do I choose $x_1,x_2$? 2. Why does $|f'|\ge|g'|$ imply the condition? It seems to me that the derivative is just the special case, how does it imply the general case?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? The fact is that I've already got to the step where I need to maximize the interval (and I don't know how to proceed) and tried LMVT (again, not fruitful at all). The reason I didn't pose them here is that I don't think they lead to any solution. So please, complete the remaining steps?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie I have updated my answer according to your requests. Please check if it helps.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I don't think this is the correct answer: the range of $a$ should be independent of the choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I agree with Solitary. Now you've added two variables which are dependent upon $x_1, x_2$, which makes it even more confusing. Now I think I need to get the minimum of $e^{c_1}-2c_2$, which is just $e^0-2\cdot2$, or $-3$, which is absurd, because similarly we see that the maximum of $-e^{c_1}-2c_2$ is $-1$. Seriously, have you *really* finished the solution?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat And I can't see what you're really doing? Adding two variables? I know that the answer is something involving $2\ln2$, yet I have no idea how your answer leads to something like that.